# Can't add to cookie manager after clearing

Tags: jmeter

I have a preprocessing beanshell script in which I was previously adding cookies from the input file and it was working perfectly.  I recently added a line to clear the cookies before adding them since I have multiple requests per loop now and don't want the response from the first request to set cookies on the second request.

```
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.CookieManager;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Cookie;
String value=vars.get("header");
if(value!=null && value!=""){
    String cookiesStr=value.replace(";+",";");
    String[] cookies= cookiesStr.split(";");
    CookieManager manager = sampler.getCookieManager();
    manager.clear();
    for(int i=0;i<cookies.length;i++){
        String[]  cookieNameVal= cookies[i].split("=");
        if(cookieNameVal.length>=2){
            Cookie cookietidal = new Cookie(cookieNameVal[0],cookieNameVal[1],"domain1.com","/", false,-1); 
            Cookie cookievlg = new Cookie(cookieNameVal[0],cookieNameVal[1],"domain2.com","/", false,-1);

            manager.add(cookie1);
            manager.add(cookie2);
        }

    }
}
```

Now this clears the cookies, but it doesn't add any afterward.  I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

I finally tried just creating a different instance of the cookie manager under each HTTP Request in my thread group.  No need to clear them now.